# Azure linux virtual machine terraform map variable issue

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using the below terraform script values for my azurerm_linux_virtual_machine terraform script but getting below error:

*"The given value is not suitable for var.vm_properties declared at variables.tf:147,1-25: element "os_disk": attributes "os_disk" and "source_image" are required.*

I have tried all the possible changes I could think of but it is not working. I am not able to understand what am I missing here

**main.tf file entry:**

```
  os_disk {
    name                 = var.vm_properties["os_disk"]["name"]
    caching              = var.vm_properties["os_disk"]["caching"]
    storage_account_type = var.vm_properties["os_disk"]["storage_account_type"]
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = var.vm_properties["source_image"]["publisher"]
    offer     = var.vm_properties["source_image"]["offer"]
    sku       = var.vm_properties["source_image"]["sku"]
    version   = var.vm_properties["source_image"]["version"]
  }
```

**variables.tf file entry :**

```
variable "vm_properties" {
  type = map(object({
    os_disk = object({
      name                 = string
      caching              = string
      storage_account_type = string
    })
    source_image = object({
      publisher = string
      offer     = string
      sku       = string
      version   = string
    })
  }))
}
```

**terraform.tfvars file entry:**

```
vm_properties = {
  os_disk = {
    name                 = "myOsDisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }
  source_image = {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have defined your variable as a `map(object...)`, it will require a key as well, e.g.:

```
vm_properties = {
  "somekeyvalue" = {
    os_disk = {
      caching              = "value"
      name                 = "value"
      storage_account_type = "value"
    }
    source_image = {
      offer     = "value"
      publisher = "value"
      sku       = "value"
      version   = "value"
    }
  }
}
```

To fix this, you can define your variable as `object(...)`:

```
variable "vm_properties" {
  type = object({
    os_disk = object({
      name                 = string
      caching              = string
      storage_account_type = string
    })
    source_image = object({
      publisher = string
      offer     = string
      sku       = string
      version   = string
    })
  })
}
```

The value you have assigned to the variable will then be valid.

Comment: You are genius. Thank you so much. I hope there was enough documentation or material available online to help with these kind of issues.

Comment: Haha, not a genius, just a lot of trial and error. :)

Comment: I need your expert help on one more question. But it is not letting me post any question because of 90 minutes time limit. I will post the question as soon as the time limit is over. I am sure it will be piece of cake for you. But I struggled for a day to solve this.

Comment: This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852581/azure-function-apps-terraform-issue. Can I please request your help on this.