# Azure function apps terraform issue

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using below terraform script values but getting below error:

*" The given value is not suitable for var.function_apps declared at variables.tf:307,1-25: element 0: attribute "site_config": element "always_on":  object required."*

I worked on similar issues in the past and realized I might be making some silly simple mistake. Any help here will be really appreciated.

**main.tf file entry:**

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_apps" {
  for_each = { for idx, app in var.function_apps : idx => app }

  name                = each.value["name"]
  location            = var.azure_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  
  storage_account_name       = var.storage_account_name
  storage_account_access_key = var.storage_account_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_app_service_plan.app_plan.id

  site_config {
    always_on          = lookup(each.value, "always_on", true)
    linux_fx_version   = lookup(each.value, "linux_fx_version", "")
  }
  
  app_settings = lookup(each.value, "app_settings", {})
  
  identity {
    type = lookup(each.value, "identity_type", "SystemAssigned")
  }

  tags = var.tags
}
```

**variables.tf file entry :**

```
variable "function_apps" {
  description = "List of maps containing configurations for each Azure Container Group."
  type = list(object({
    name                = string
    version            = string
    site_config          = map(object({
      always_on                 = bool
      linux_fx_version          = string
    }))
    app_settings          = optional(map(string))
    identity_type      = optional(string)
  }))
    
  default = []
}
```

**terraform.tfvars file entry:**

```
function_apps = [
  {
    name    = "s3-copier"
    version = " ~3"

    site_config = {
      always_on = true
      linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|mydockerregistry/myfunctionapp:latest"
    }

    app_settings = {
      FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = "dotnet"
      WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = "1"
    }

    identity_type = "SystemAssigned"
  },
  {
    name    = "notification-processor"
    version = " ~3"

    site_config = {
      always_on        = true
      linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|mydockerregistry/myfunctionapp:latest"
    }

    app_settings = {
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "node"
      "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" = "1"
    }

    identity_type = "SystemAssigned"
  },
  {
    name    = "upload-processor"
    version = " ~3"

    site_config = {
      always_on        = true
      linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|mydockerregistry/myfunctionapp:latest"
    }

    app_settings = {
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "node"
      "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" = "1"
    }

    identity_type = "SystemAssigned"
  },
]
```

Comment: Can you try with `lookup(each.value.site_config, "always_on", true)`?

Answer (score 0):

Yous can use

```
  site_config {
    always_on          = try(each.value.site_config.always_on, true)
    linux_fx_version   = try(each.value.site_config.linux_fx_version, "")
  }
```